# Keycloak Realm-specific authorization following cross-realm authentication

Tags: java, plugins, keycloak

Is it possible to trigger any mechanism to fetch realm-specific roles for an authenticated user (a linked user, after cross-realm authentication) in Keycloak?

My company has its own corporate authentication and authorization services.
I have configured a segregated 'authentication-only' realm with a user federation (plugin) that calls our corporate authentication Service.
This works fine - we have apps in distinct realms (A and B) whose identity provider points to the the broker client of the realm above. These Id providers are set (on First Login Flow) to create and link their migrated realm users to the original realm, and this way we are able to establish SSO.

Now we need to assign realm-specific roles in realms A and B. 
For that I tried adding a another (authorization-specific) UserFederation plugin (tried intercepting 'validate' from ImportedUserValidation, to call our authorization corporate service) - this time on realms A and B, but it is never triggered.. Due to the existence of their Identity Provider, maybe? 
Should my specific authorization mechanism be set somehow under Post Login Flow?

Any recommendations?

Many thanks, regards

Answer (score 0):

Found a way with User Federation, a bit cumbersome - It works if the user does not exist in the realm. So first I define its Cache Policy as MAX_LIFESPAN (a few minutes), then on getUserByUsername from my plugin (that implements UserLookupProvider) I create a User Model (from AbstractUserAdapterFederatedStorage) overriding

> public Set getRoleMappings() {...

At this method I am able to retrieve my realm-specif user roles, from my corporate service